# jks TrustStore File Cannot be found on Anypoint RTF

Tags: mulesoft, mule4, anypoint-rtf

I have a jks file that is deployed to `src/main/resources`. In my `global.xml`, I set the `path` to `server_truststore.jks` and password. When I deploy to Anypoint, I get the following error:

```
1 or more replicas in unexpected state: [Kubernetes] CrashLoopBackOff
 - Resource server_truststore.jks could not be found
```

Runtime: 4.3
Platform: Runtime Fabric

I have no idea what to do at this point. I don't think I can configure my TLS...

global.xml snippet:

```
<kafka:producer-config name="Apache_Kafka_Producer_configuration" doc:name="Apache Kafka Producer configuration" doc:id="a1830b08-51cd-4c63-9993-db5eff4d8a17" topic="${kafka.producer.publishTopicSubscriptionPattern}">
        <kafka:producer-sasl-plain-connection username="${kafka.saslUsername}" password="${kafka.saslPassword}">
            <reconnection >
                <reconnect frequency="${kafka.producer.retry.interval}" count="${kafka.producer.retry.count}" />
            </reconnection>
            <tls:context >
                <tls:trust-store path="server_truststore.jks" password="${kafka.tls.trustStore.password}" type="jks"/>
            </tls:context>
            <kafka:bootstrap-servers >
                <kafka:bootstrap-server value="${kafka.serverUrl}" />
            </kafka:bootstrap-servers>
        </kafka:producer-sasl-plain-connection>
    </kafka:producer-config>
```

Comment: Please share the XML configuration snippet that references that file. No screenshots please. Is it really a trust store or a keystore?  Is the configuration file a .XAML?

Comment: it's a truststore. My apologies, I typed xaml but it's an xml.

Comment: Ok. Version of the Kafka connector?

Comment: connector version: 4.5.2

Answer (score 0):

It is possible that the connector's TLS configuration requires an absolute path. You can build it by using predefined property placeholders:

```xml
<tls:trust-store path="${mule.home}/apps/${app.name}/server_truststore.jks" ... />
```

See https://help.mulesoft.com/s/article/How-to-set-the-working-directory-path-relative-to-the-deployment-folder-in-Mule-4 for reference

Comment: I had seen this and I had only questioned it because it doesn't confirm if these placeholders get populated for RTF as well. I will give it a shot and redeploy and confirm back to you

Comment: They are populated by the Mule runtime, not RTF, so they should work in any deployment model.